# Applying Email template creator ( paperbits.io ) to Angular 6+

Tags: angular, angular6

I didn't see any examples which use paperbit.io like and imported module. I see demo project only. who used them please let me know how to install paperbit.io package

Comment: I googled "Angular paperbits.io" and it seems like the "Getting Started" guide has all the information you need: https://paperbits.io/wiki/ui-frameworks. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users for the steps expected of people before they ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be ways to use paperbits in an Angular Project, but no documentation for doing so. For now, I'd recommend trial and error with the usual way of installing packages with npm and going through the code on Github to know which packages to import.

You can also wait till official documentation is available. Using it right now will be like going in blind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer maybe I will use another tools